# How to handle int exception?

Tags: c#, exception

I'm trying to handle the situation of entering a string instead of an int.
for example

```
newCustomer.PhoneNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
if (newCustomer.PhoneNum < 0 || newCustomer.PhoneNum > 10000000000 || newCustomer.PhoneNum.GetType() != typeof (int))
{
    throw new CustomException(newCustomer.PhoneNum.ToString());
}
```

obviously the last condition of the if is not right but I am out of ideas.

Comment: Int32.TryParse is what you need

Comment: There are multiple ways to handle exceptions and validation - you need to be absolutely clear on what your conditions are, and what tech you're using before we can really help.

Comment: Note that it is usually not the best solution to represent a phone number as an integer. You may need special characters such as +, #, or * in exotic cases, and leading zeroes may be significant.

Comment: Is a 32-bit integer sufficient for your needs? I can't see a locale on your profile but it wouldn't be large enough to hold a US or UK phone number, and definitely wouldn't hold most numbers if prefixed with international country codes.

Comment: Sidenote: Don't try to save a phone number as an int, that is a bad idea. A string should be fine for most cases. It's not likely you will ever need the numeric values anyway.

Comment: Yes, converting a phone number to an INT (or validating it as an INT) is a very bad idea, as casting will case it to lose any leading zeros... plus valid phone numbers have many permutations and characters. #, -, * and whitespace are common in phone numbers, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string text1 = "x";
int num1;
if (!int.TryParse(text1, out num1))
{
    // String is not a number.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check what has been input first by using int.TryParse which will put the value into the out parameter if it is a valid integer or return false if it's not.

```
int phoneNumber;
string input = Console.ReadLine();

if (!int.TryParse(input, out phoneNumber))
{
    throw new CustomException(input);
}
else if (phoneNumber < 0 || phoneNumber > 10000000000
{
    throw new CustomException(phoneNumber);
}

newCustomer.PhoneNum = phoneNumber;
```

Obviously I have just reproduced the validation logic you specified in your example but it seems a bit simplistic and will probably throw out perfectly valid phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with raw data, you can use int.TryParse() as already mentioned.

However, if you're trying to validate more complex rules, you might want to use something like the FluentValidation nuget package, which I absolutely love. It makes validation a much more pleasurable experience :)

http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/

Alternatively, if you're using something like ASP.Net or MVC, there are built in validation engines. In MVC you can use model Data Annotations to do both client and server side validation very easily (and in an organised way). Check out [unobtrusive validation](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
    int i;
    string n=textbox1.Text;
    bool success = int.TryParse(n, out i);

//if the parse was successful, success is true

    if(success)
    {
    //do ur code

    }
    else
    {

     throw new CustomException(newCustomer.PhoneNum.ToString());
    }
```